# Spring-boot actuator - trace to file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In spring boot we have trace endpoint.  Is it possible to redirect these entries into file ?  I was trying to find this in internet, but no effects.

Answer (score 1):

First you can Implement your own class from TraceRepository. Then save it to a file with Logger. You can find a production ready sample here which is a way to [save actuator to file](https://github.com/coditori/javatori/tree/master/projects/spring-boot-actuator-logger) per any request.

Comment: thank you, indeed it's a production-ready sample.

Comment: Link is now dead and no alternative exists, only in-memory example in repo.

Comment: @Encryption link has been updated

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add a more complete solution similar to what I ended up doing, but no matter what you end up needing to create a CustomTraceRepository class that implements `HttpTraceRepository` because Spring Framework handles calling the `add` method from somewhere in the FilterChains, when its enabled.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomHttpTraceRepository implements HttpTraceRepository {

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

AtomicReference<HttpTrace> lastTrace = new AtomicReference<>();

@Override
public void add(HttpTrace trace) {
    // Leverage the parameter Trace object
    lastTrace.set(trace);
    try {
        log.info(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(lastTrace.get()));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

@Override
public List<HttpTrace> findAll() {
    synchronized (this.contents) {
        return new ArrayList<>(); // Do not use / leave return empty list
    }
}
```

}